# Disconnecting battery cable from Asus Zenbook ux530ux motherboard

Tags: battery, asus-laptop

Hi could you help me to disconnect the battery from the motherboard, please? I've tried pulling it upwards but it doesn't seem to unplug and I'm scared if I apply too much pressure I'll break it. Am I doing it the right way?

[image]

Comment: It slides backwards (toward wires), not upwards.

Comment: It can't slide backwards because the black pins are holding it :/

Comment: those are the locks, see if they depress or with a pick pry up on the white plastic (left of the lock in the image) as you pull, be careful. It could be the one in the center locking it.